# SVG View Box not working on iPhone

Tags: svg, viewbox

I have been working on a simple one page site and as the user scrolls the logo expands. This works well on the desktop but when I check it on IOS it doesn't work - it does work on android. Any thoughts out there? You can see it here.

http://dev.floe.se

Comment: Fails on Firefox desktop, too. I'm afraid letter-spacing on SVG is poorly supported.

Comment: Have you tried with kerning?

Comment: @llobet No. Any tips on how that might work!

Comment: Kerning is a svg property such as letter-spacing but much more supported. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/kerning